# Проблемы с копированием файла

Tags: visual-studio

Проект говорит, что не находит файл, хотя он есть

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Database.s3db"));
```

> Не удается найти указанный файл. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файла нет -- К.О.

Comment: Но..ведь он есть)

Comment: А вы в выходной папке проверьте...

Comment: @pavel-mayorov в папке из которой должно копироваться (Assets) он есть, соответственно в папке, в которую должно копироваться - нету

Comment: Ну так и задавайте вопрос, почему его там нет. Причем тут вообще ваш метод ToStorage() и копирование файла в нем?

Comment: @pavel-mayorov вопрос в том, почему не видит файл, который нужно скопировать, при чем именно *.s3db-файл, хотя этот файл есть. Остальные же файлы копирует этот метод

Comment: Вы понимаете или нет, что файл не будет виден независимо от того что вы с ним будете делать? Ошибка-то у вас не в алгоритме копирования!

Comment: @pavel-mayorov дело в том, что я не понимаю почему его не видит, если он есть) возможно возникло недопонимание.
есть папка Assets, в ней лежит *.ttf и *.s3db. *.ttf-файл видит, а *s3db нет. Вот и не понимаю, ПОЧЕМУ его не видит, а код приложил на тот случай, если все-таки в нем ошибка.

Comment: Выкладывание случайных кусков кода не поможет найти причину. Лучше приведите фрагменты файла проекта, где эти файлы описаны (открыть файл проекта можно любым текстовым редактором).

Comment: @pavel-mayorov если я правильно понял, то...
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- A reference to the entire .Net Framework and Windows SDK are automatically included -->
    <Content Include="Assets\MoneyKeeperIcons.ttf" />
    <None Include="Assets\Database.s3db" />
    <None Include="project.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @pavel-mayorov Все, поменял None на Content, заработало) Спасибо!

Comment: коллеги, оформили бы ответ раз уж нашли решение, чтобы вопрос не висел открытым. И метку `visual-studio` или в чем там проект был написан, добавить можно вместо `uwp` и `C#`, которые тут в общем-то ни при чём.

Comment: @rdorn а как это сделать?))

Comment: что именно? метки? кнопка `править` под вашим вопросом.

Comment: @rdorn закрыть вопрос. буквально день тут, не нашел такой кнопочки)

Comment: сорри, я имел в виду, что вопрос без ответа висит. Вы в можете сами написать ответ и принять его через 3 дня кажется, или попросить Павла оформить ответ и принять его. К сожалению тут нельзя обратиться в чате сразу ко всем, чтобы пришло оповещение, так что подозреваю, что оповещение о моей просьбе получили только вы.

Comment: если считаете что он бесполезен для других посетителей, можете просто удалить его, но я бы просто переформулировал его так, чтобы стала понятна суть вашей проблемы и дописал решение.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы нужно открыть файл проекта в любом текстовом редакторе, найти там строчку (в моем случае):

```
<None Include="Assets\Database.s3db" />
```

и заменить `None` на `Content`